# Retrieving data in DataGridView by matching TextBox content

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I have 3 tables in database as:

1. Emp(name ,cellnumber,payment,Joining_date)
2. Addmoney(name,date_of money_taken,Type)
3. AddDate(name,Leaving_Date)

I want to display only these columns from these 3 table (name, payment, Date_of_money_Taken, Joining_date, Leaving_date), when user enters any name stored in Emp table in a TextBox, I have a problem in the code below. It is throwing this:

`Exception({"The multi-part identifier \"name.Text\" could not be bound."})`

```
private void ShowEmp_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // create the connection string
    connectionString = GetConnectionString();
    connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    queryString = "select Emp.name,Emp.Payment,Emp.JoiningDate,Addm.Date,AddDate.LeavingDate from Emp,Addm,AddDate where name.Text='" + name + " ' ";// Select * From Emp

    // create an SqlDataAdapter to execute the query
    dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection);

    // create a command builder
    cBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dAdapter);

    // create a datatable to hold query results
    dTable = new DataTable();

    // fill DataTable
    dAdapter.Fill(dTable);<-EXCEPTION({"The multi-part identifier \"name.Text\" could not be bound."})

    // the DataGridView
    //DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();

    // BindingSource to sync DataTable and DataGridView
    bSource = new BindingSource();

    // set the BindingSource DataSource
    bSource.DataSource = dTable;

    // set the DataGridView DataSource
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;

}
```

Comment: I notice that this method is all inside the 'Load' event handler so it will only get called once on load, is this the desired effect or did you want the lookup to happen on a button click or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't your query wrong?  Try this for the query:

```
queryString = "
    select 
        Emp.name, Emp.Payment, Emp.JoiningDate, Addm.Date, AddDate.LeavingDate
    from
        Emp, Addm, AddDate where Emp.name = '" + name + "' ";
```

You are referencing `name.Text` when it looks like the field name should be `Emp.name`.

Note, you **REALLY** need to do this using params.  This is wide open for a SQL injection...

Comment: but after using this querystring how can i display the data in datagridview ,becaus now it is not displaying anything in datagridview

Comment: @Anonynus You will need to figure that out as there is probably a problem with how you are wiring up the result.  Can you get the grid to display anything at all even with no filtering?  Are you sure the text in the name is making an exact match?  Maybe you need a `LIKE` instead of `=` check in your SQL.  There are ton things that could be wrong.  Do some diagnosing and repost.